# Recoverability of schedule

Tags: database, database-design, schedule

Em, hello, I have a question about two schedules and it's recoverability. I'm not sure if I've understood lessons and the whole definitions, so I would be grateful if someone could tell me if I'm right with this.

First schedule is:

```
T1    T2    T3
R1(x)
      R2(x)
W1(x)
            R3(x)
            W3(x)
C1
      C2
            C3
```

This one in my opinion is recoverable, because T3, as reads after T1 have written something, is committed after T1.

Second schedule is:

```
T1    T2    T3
      W2(x)
R1(y)
W1(y)
            R3(x)
            W3(x)
C1
            C3
      C2
```

This one is not recoverable, because T3 reads x after T2 have written something and T3 is committed before T2. I'm not sure if T1 is also making this schedule not recoverable, but it reads y, not x.
Am I right? Again, I would be grateful for the answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the definition and show whether it is satisfied:

[Recoverable schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schedule_%28computer_science%29#Recoverable):

> Transactions commit only after all transactions whose changes they read, commit.

First schedule:

- T1: Reads no changes, so commits only after all transactions whose changes it reads commit.
- T2: Reads no changes, so commits only after all transactions whose changes it reads commit.
- T3: Reads changed x, but commits only after all transactions whose changes it reads commit.

All transactions commit only after all transactions whose changes they read commit. Recoverable.

Second schedule:

- T1: Reads no changes, so commits only after all transactions whose changes it reads commit.
- T2: Reads no changes, so commits only after all transactions whose changes it reads commit.
- T3: Reads changed x, but commits before all transactions whose changes it reads commit.

Not all transactions commit only after all transactions whose changes they read commit. Not recoverable.